# Git source tree переключение между ветками старая версия файла

Tags: c#, git, source-tree

Работаю в Visual studio 2015 c Source Tree, при переключении между ветками в файле формата *.csv подгружается в CLR старая версия файла. В Sollution Explorer вижу измененную версию.Прошу помощи

Comment: а фиксировали ли гит после внесения изменений?

Comment: В старой ветке я изменения на полочку положил, и переключился на новую. Не комитил

Comment: можно немного расшифровать, а то я не понял ничего? Вы перешли на другую ветку и контент файла csv изменился? Так вроде и должно быть. Как вы это заметили в Sollution Explorer, если там не показывает контент файла, а только имя файла?

Comment: В expolrer е стоит правильная версия файла, однако загружаются данные из старой версии данного файла

Comment: куда загружаются?